# Concentration or distribution of the scaled $l_p$ norm of a correlation matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

**Background:**

Among Hermitan random matrices, correlation matrix has a lot of applications in statistics. People have studied the "empirical spectral distribution (ESD)" of a correlation matrix, the largest eigenvalue of a correlation matrix, the log determinant of a correlation matrix, the largest off-diagonal entries of a correlation matrix, all with applications to statistics. However, there seems to be no work on the scaled $l_p$ norm of a correlation matrix. The $l_p$ norm of a correlation matrix provides a criterion on if the "strong law of large numbers (SLLN)" associated with the classic normal means problem holds.

**Problem statement:**

Let $x_i, i=1, \ldots,n$ be $n$ i.i.d. observations from a $m$-dimensional random vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $x$ has correlation matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, let $R = (r_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be the correlation matrix obtained from $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$ such that each $r_{ij}$ is a Pearson correlation coefficient, and let the $l_p$ norm of $R$ be $$\Vert R \Vert_p = \sum_{i,j=m}^p \vert r_{ij} \vert^p$$ for $0<p<\infty$.

Consider the case $p=1$. Then $\Vert R \Vert_1 \ge m$. Assume that for some $\alpha >0$, the scaled $l_p$ norm $m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1$ almost surely or with probability tending to $1$ lies in a compact interval, say, $[a,b]$. What can be said about $$\Pr(\vert m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1 - \mathbb{E}(m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1) \vert > t)$$ for a fixed $t >0$ when $m$ is large (and $n$ satisfies some relationship with $m$), where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation?

[**edits added**]
The problem is non-trivial since, first of all, the existence of $\alpha$ remains to be solved, and the behavior of $m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1$ depends critically on $\Sigma$, $n$, $p$ and the tail behavior of the probability distribution of $x$. Often a phase transition can be observed or proved for the distribution of $m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1$, depending on the aforementioned aspects. The key complications for a neat analysis are (1) that the entries of $R$ are not independent and can be long-range dependent and (2) the accumulation of noise contributed by the $m(m-1)/2$ terms in the sum for $\Vert R \Vert_1$. [**edits added**]

**Specialization to Gaussian $x$:**

If $x$ follows a Gaussian distribution, then each entry $r_{ij}$, being a Pearson correlation coefficient, has an explicit marginal distribution, and the covariance between $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$ is given by JH Steiger's paper here (https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1980-08757-001). These results were also provided by Pearson and Filon (and Steiger's paper quoted these results). However, the notations of Pearson and Filon are very much outdated (compared to modern notations) and are hard to digest.

To study $m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1$ and its concentration properties, and in particular, to show the SLLN for $m^{-\alpha}\Vert R \Vert_1$ (using techniques of triangular arrays), we need the covariance between the absolute values of $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$, i.e., we need $$\mathsf{cov}(\vert r_{ij} \vert, \vert r_{jk} \vert)$$ This then requires the joint distribution of $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$, which I am not able to find an existing formula (and whose derivation is going to be very tedious and cumbersome).

**Specialized question and attempts:**

Does anyone know the joint distribution of $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$? Caution: one should not attempt to obtain the joint distribution of $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$ by using the distribution of $R$ when $x$ is Gaussian (even though in this case $R$ has an analytic density involving its determinant) since it induces more chaos than directly computing the covariance using a tri-variate normal distribution. [**edits added**] The reason for this is that even though for the Gaussian case $R$ has a density $f$, finding the joint distribution for $r_{ij}$ and $r_{jk}$ from this density requires integrating out $m(m-1)/2 -2 $ parameters from $f$, i.e., doing a $m(m-1)/2 -2 $-dimensional integral, and compute a Jacobian. [**edits added**]

Comment: To the down-voter: I am posting this problem and focusing on a special case for which there seems to be no literature. Why did you down-vote it? If someone else knows the answer to my specialized question, it could save me some time doing the tedious manual computation and there is no need to reinvent something existent. Would not this be a good thing? On the contrary, the problem in the title of the post is rarely studied in random matrix theory. Besides, studying correlation matrix is harder than Hermitian random matrix with i.i.d upper-triangular entries. Why did you think this is trivial?

Comment: To the down-voter: if you thought that my questions are trivial, could you please write down your comments? Do not abuse your rights on mathoverflow and somebody else’s intellectual inquiry. Thanks

Comment: The behavior of the scaled $l_p$ norm will show different behavior depending on properties of $\Sigma$ and magnitudes of $n$ and $p$ and the tail behavior of $x$